# Pytorch Lightning - How to log a W&B histogram?

Tags: pytorch-lightning, wandb

Lightning AI has a W&B logger (https://lightning.ai/docs/pytorch/latest/extensions/generated/pytorch_lightning.loggers.WandbLogger.html), but the documentation doesn't specify how to log a W&B Histogram. Can someone please tell me how to log a W&B histogram via `WandbLogger`?

Answer (score 2):

A quick workaround until a proper solution is found:

You can construct the plot using wandb as normal, and then give it to the lightning backend through `lightning.pytorch.LightningModule.logger.experiment.log()`.
Inside your lightning module you can call

```
data = [[v] for v in values]
table = wandb.Table(data=data, columns=["values"])
hist = wandb.plot.histogram(table, "values")
self.logger.experiment.log({"histogram_values": hist})
```

This will make wandb throw an error if `wandb.init()` has not been initialized.
To get around this call `wandb.init(mode="offline")` after `lightning.pytorch.loggers.WandbLogger()`. Now the plot will also be visible through `WandbLogger()`.

Answer (score 0):

What are you looking to plot with histograms?

Here’s how to make histograms with arbitrary data:

```
data = [[s] for s in scores]
table = wandb.Table(data=data, columns=["scores"])
wandb.log({'my_histogram': wandb.plot.histogram(table, "scores", title="Prediction Score Distribution")})
```

https://wandb.ai/wandb/plots/reports/Creating-Custom-Histograms-With-Weights-Biases--VmlldzoyNzE0NzM

If you’re looking to watch the gradients of your model, you can call wandb.watch on your PyTorch nn.module

Comment: This doesn't use Lightning's `WandbLogger`, which is what my question concerns. Can you please explain how to use `WandbLogger` to log a histogram?

Comment: # log gradients and model topology
wandb_logger.watch(model)

Comment: That's for the gradients and model topology. I want to know how to log a generic histogram e.g. `np.random.random(100)`

Comment: The above `wandb.plot.historgram` can be used within PyTorch Lightning, but you'll need to use wandb directly rather than relying on their logger. You can call wandb within one of the training loop methods they have.

Answer (score 0):

One somehow **stupid** method:

run `wandb.init()` manually before constructing the trainer. Then invoke `wandb.log` in your training step. For example:

```
# main()
wandb.init()
trainer = Trainer(**other_args,
                logger=WandbLogger(project='wandb_output'),
                )
trainer.fit(model, dataloader)
```

```
# forward()
wandb.log({'data': data})
```

There will be two wandb links, you can find all the logs in the former one.